# Where are the PHP5 session files temporarily stored using Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: session, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.5

Where are the PHP5 session files temporarily stored using Ubuntu 14.04?

My /tmp dir contains only these files and I do not know where they are belonging to:
- global.dir
- global.pag
- ip.dir
- ip.pag

Answer (score 0):

### session_save_path

To get the current session save path just call the 'session_save_path' function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

```
<?php

echo session_save_path();
```